# What mechanism does println use?

Tags: java

I know the `println` method of the `System.out` object can be used to print any object, regardless of which class it belongs to. But can anyone tell me the mechanism that `println` uses to accomplish this task?

Comment: Why don't you look at source code once ?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ the mechanism is not immediately obvious.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: at least in JDK 7, `println(Object o)` just calls `String.valueOf(o)`, which in turn checks for `null` and calls `o.toString()`. That's just three clicks in an IDE to find out...

Answer (score 7):

Calling `System.out.println` on an object uses `Object`'s `toString()` method - either the default implementation in `Object` class, or the implementations of classes that override this default.

System.out.println, eventually uses one of `PrintStream`'s various `println` methods, since `System.out` is a `PrintStream` instance.

If you pass a `String` to `System.out.println`, it will call `println(String)`. If you pass a `char[]` to it, it will call `println(char[])`. If you pass any other type of `Object`, it will call `println(Object)` (unless the compiler decides to convert the `Object` to a `String`, using the object's `toString()` method, and then call `println(String)` instead).

`println(Object x)` converts the `Object` to a `String` by calling `String.valueOf()`, which returns either "null" (for null Objects) or `obj.toString()`.

Either way, the `Object`'s `toString()` method is used, unless the `Object` is null.

Comment: The `println` method only accepts `String` input.  It's the compiler's logic that uses the `toString()` method when appropriate.  Since `println` expects a `String` and not an `Object` (unless it's a `String` object), the compiler will convert the object to a `String` via the `toString()` method.  This is no different than doing the following:  `final Object o = new SomeObject();final String oString = "" + o;`

Comment: @Jared `println` is overloaded to accept an `Object` input (also a `boolean`, `int`, `float` etc.). You can see that from the API.

Comment: @Jared PrintStream has many overloaded versions of println. Some accept primitives, one accepts a String and one accepts an Object.

Comment: @khelwood That's a good point, but I don't think it has anything to do with printing `Object`'s via the `toString()` method.

Comment: @Jared No, I was just correcting the wrong information in your comment.

Comment: @Jared System.out is a PrintStream. System.out.println calls one of PrintStream's methods. System.out.println(object) calls PrintStream's println(Object x), which calls String.valueOf(x) which calls x.toString(). Therefore the Object's toString() method is used in order to print the object.

Comment: @Eran First off, I frankly don't see how the API complies with the Java compiler because a `String` object is also of type `Object` so it seems to me there should be a conflict there, but ultimately it doesn't really matter because the `PrintStream.print(Object o)` method just calls the `toString()` method anyway (or prints `null`).  The logic is still no different than when concatenating strings (as I showed in my initial comment).

Comment: @Jared You seem to be in some confusion about the way overloading works.

Comment: @Eran I will grant you that the two following codes are "different": `final Object o = new Integer(3); System.out.println(o);` and `final Object o = new Integer(3); System.out.println("Integer o is: " + o);`  But the second is a compiler thing--which is converting `o` to a `String` via the `toString()` method and concatenating it with the given `String`--and it clearly does this dynamically (not statically).

Comment: @Jared I guess the compiler can decide which version of println to call. If you pass a String to println (System.out.println(" something " + someObject), the compiler must convert the parameter to a String and call println(String). However, if you just call System.out.println(someObject), it can either pass that object directly to println(Object) or pass someObject.toString() to println(String).

Comment: @Eran There is a subtlety here, which is that fact that `println()` will print `null` for a null object, which means it's _not_ calling the `toString()` method (which would cause a `NullPointerException`).  The same (I believe) is true when you concatenate a `String` with an object as opposed to calling its `toString()` method explicitly (which _would_ result in a `NullPointerException` if the object was `null`).

Comment: @Jared I already mentioned that in my answer - `println(Object x) converts the Object to a String by calling String.valueOf(), which returns either "null" (for null Objects) or obj.toString()`

Comment: @Jared My edit regarding String.valueOf() was prior to your "There is a subtlety" comment. I agree about the last part of your comment, and edited the answer. I think we can end this discussion (I don't really care if you cancel your down vote or not).

Answer (score -1):

There is very little difference between the way `PrintStream/PrintWriter.println(...)` treats `String`'s and the way the compiler treats `String`'s.  The print streams will automatically convert an `Object` to a `String` via the `toString()` method unless that object is `null` (in which case it prints `null`).  The difference is that you cannot set a `String` object to a general `Object`--but you *can* concatenate a `String` object with a general purpose `Object` which will be concatenated via the `toString()` method (unless the `Object` is `null`).  Frankly, this is normallly how you would use the `toString()` method.  Here is a sample program that illustrates the differences:

```
public class PrintStreamTester {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        final MyObject o1 = null;
        final MyObject o2 = new MyObject("blah blah blah");

        String s1 = "o1.toString() failed";

        try {
            s1 = o1.toString();
        } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
            // who cares
        }
        final String s2 = "" + o1;
        final String s3 = o2.toString();
        final String s4 = "" + o2;

        System.out.println("o1 by itself (below):");
        System.out.println(o1);
        System.out.println("o1's toString(): " + s1);
        System.out.println("o1's \"\" + o1: " + s2);

        System.out.println("o2 by itself (below):");
        System.out.println(o2);
        System.out.println("o2's toString(): " + s3);
        System.out.println("o2's \"\" + o1: " + s4);
    }
}

class MyObject {
    private final String string;

    public MyObject(final String string) {
        this.string = string;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return string;
    }
}
```

Here is the output from this program:

```
o1 by itself (below):
null
o1's toString(): o1.toString() failed
o1's "" + o1: null
o2 by itself (below):
blah blah blah
o2's toString(): blah blah blah
o2's "" + o1: blah blah blah
```