# Why BufferedWriter write() method does not autocast to String

Tags: java

I came this behavior of java which for me seems a bit strange.

While I was checking this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27520396/3584765) I did realize that the `write()` method of `BufferedWriter` is not applicable for `Long` objects:

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outFile));
Long l1 = new Long(1);
writer.write(l1); // <- this won't work as it is
```

While I have been using `BufferedWriter` a lot, it has been in the format to write multiple values using separators:

```
writer.write(l1 + ","); //<- this works fine.
```

So, I am guessing the part that makes a difference is the `+ ","` part which virtually calls `l1.toString() + ","` before providing it as input to `BufferedWriter`.

My question is why java does not apply autocasting to `String` to these cases. I mean what problem would there be since `write()` expects:

1. either an `int` in a method implemented in `BufferedWriter`
2. or an array of characters
3. or a `String` in `Writer` class.

Would there be any ambiguity regarding the desired result?

In a similar (according to my perceptive) `System.out.print()` in `PrintStream` works flawlessly:

```
System.out.println(l1); // <- this works fine
```

`PrintStream` does not contain a `println(Long)` method either. Does this mean it is converted first to `long` and then it is used this method (`out.print(long)`) and so this step cannot be completed in the case of `BufferedWriter`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What mechanism does println use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26583058/what-mechanism-does-println-use/26583069#comment41782483_26583069).

Comment: @Jared I am not asking about `println` here though but rather about the `BufferedWriter`. This was just an example and it could be deleted (the example)

Comment: PrintStream does contain a `println(long)` overload though.

Comment: I understand that, but the point is that `System.out.println(...)` has a [`PrintStream.println(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-java.lang.Object-) method where as `BufferedWriter` _has no_ `write(Object)` method.  Now why doesn't it?  That I cannot answer.

Comment: @Jared Likely because the job of a Writer is to write text (and leaving it up to you to convert the data you have in your own manner to text), while the job of a PrintStream, according to its docs is "print representations of various data values conveniently".

Comment: @nos You and John Smith are probably right, especially noting that there _is_ a [`PrintWriter.print/ln(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#println-java.lang.Object-) method.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as "auto-casting to `String`" in Java. What is there is that when the "`+`"-operator is used in a String context, the operands will be converted to Strings. This means that the implicit conversion which you're looking for only happens in the context of the "`+`"-operator.

The available `write()` methods in `Writer` and therefore `BufferedWriter` are:

- `void write(char[] cbuf)` - Writes an array of characters.
- `void write(char[] cbuf, int off, int len)` - Writes a portion of an array of characters.
- `void write(int c)` - Writes a single character.
- `void write(String str)` - Writes a string.
- `void write(String str, int off, int len)` - Writes a portion of a string.

If you want to write something else, it will not work because the `write()` method is not overloaded with the variants that you're looking for.

What you are looking for is something like this:

- `void print(Object o)` - Writes an object, converting it to a string by calling its `toString()` method, unless `o == null`, in which case the String `"null"` will be written.

You can wrap your `BufferedWriter` with a `PrintWriter` which contains such methods; look out for methods named `print` instead of `write`. You can see that `PrintWriter` (and, for that matter, `PrintStream`) contain lots of overloaded methods for various types so that literally anything can be printed, not just `String`s and `char`acters.

So, your code code look like this:

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outFile)));
Long l1 = new Long(1);
writer.print(l1); // <- this works.
```

P.S.:
`PrintStream` as well as `PrintWriter` contain two methods which can be used: `println(long)` / `print(long)` and `println(Object)` / `print(Object)`. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html and `http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html`. Java could "choose" between using `println(Object)` and `println(long)`. If both are available, Java uses `println(Object)`, and if we think a little bit about it, it's clear why. `long` has 2^32 possible values, but `Long` has (from a logical perspective) 2^32+1 possible values, because it might as well be `null`. If we would call `println(long)` with `null`, we'd get `NullPointerException` because `(Long) null` cannot be successfully unboxed into a `long`. But `println(Object)` can work with `null`. The process of implicitly converting a primitive type like `long` to the corresponding object like `Long` is called auto-boxing, the process of the reverse is called unboxing. If given the choice, the compiler avoids unboxing.

P.P.S.:
In Java, *overloaded* means that a class or object provides multiple methods of the same name but with different parameter type lists. The compiler chooses the right method by matching the argument types with the parameter types of the candidate methods. It is possible to construct ambiguous cases, i.e. `writer.write(null)`. The ambiguity can be resolved using casts or variables, `writer.write((String) null)`, or `String s = null; writer.write(s);`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Long l1 = new Long(1);
writer.write(l1.toString()); //-> It is possible

writer.write(l1 + ",");  // here you concat the long with String it returns String
```

**Long + String - > String.**

BufferedWriter class not having any method to write the Long.

Possible write methods [BufferedWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#write(char[],%20int,%20int))

Answer (score 0):

Look at [the java language specification, section 5.4 "String context"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.4). It clearly states that the "`+`" operator, when used with strings and other objects will use string coercion on those other non-string objects.

Answer (score 0):

It seems clear to me (based on the comments) and looking at the [`Writer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html) class that the `Writer` class is *only* supposed to write single characters.  Thus asking it to print an integer value (whether long, byte, short, or whatever) is against what the class is meant to do (and the same goes for general objects).  Yes, you can pass it an integer value, but that value is *actually* a `char`--*not* an `int`--so it will print the `char` value rather than your `int` value.

The fact that `l1 + ","` works is because the compiler converts this to a `String` object (which the `Writer` then converts to a char array and writes the `String` value `char` by `char`).  Note that calling `Writer.write((int)(l1 + ','))` would have "unexpected" results).

If you want to print string representations then you should wrap the `BufferedWriter` inside a [`PrintWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html), i.e.:

```
public static PrintWriter getPrintWriter(final BufferedWriter bw){
    return new PrintWriter(bw);
}
```

I should also point out that if you want to be *extremely* careful, then you should use [`OutputStreamWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html) and specify the character encoding or character set (this may actually be more important for reading files rather than writing to them, i.e. you should use [`InputStreamReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) to read text files).